# CRUD MySQL - Return ID data only

Tags: mysql, crud

I'm creating a project in Android Studio (Beginner in programming). The project is almost finished, but I can not solve the last problem. How to return only the data entered by a user?

In MySQL, I have the saved user ID, but I can not return only the data that it saved to a ListView. The variable that stores the user ID is the "IDMestre". Here's my code:

**ViewAllEmployee**

```js
public class ViewAllEmployee extends AppCompatActivity implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView listView;
    private String JSON_STRING;

    Button btnAtualizar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all_employee);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getJSON();

        btnAtualizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAtualizar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (intent != null) {
            Bundle params = intent.getExtras();

            if (params != null) {
                String IDMestre = params.getString("IDMestre");
                TextView txtIDMestre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editIDMestre);
                txtIDMestre.setText(IDMestre);
            }
        }

        btnAtualizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(ViewAllEmployee.this, TelaInicial.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }

    private void showEmployee() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                String IDMesa = jo.getString(Config.TAG_IDMESA);
                String Nome = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NOME);

                HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
                employees.put(Config.TAG_IDMESA, IDMesa);
                employees.put(Config.TAG_NOME, Nome);
                list.add(employees);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ViewAllEmployee.this, list, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{Config.TAG_IDMESA, Config.TAG_NOME},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name});

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void getJSON() {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            ProgressDialog loading;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(ViewAllEmployee.this, "Fetching Data", "Wait...", false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                JSON_STRING = s;
                showEmployee();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s = rh.sendGetRequest(Config.URL_GET_ALL);
                return s;
            }
        }

        GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
        gj.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewEmployee.class);
        HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        String mesaId = map.get(Config.TAG_IDMESA).toString();
        intent.putExtra(Config.TBMESA_ID, mesaId);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**RequestHandler**

```js
public class RequestHandler {

    //Method to send httpPostRequest
    //This method is taking two arguments
    //First argument is the URL of the script to which we will send the request
    //Other is an HashMap with name value pairs containing the data to be send with the request



    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
        //Creating a URL
        URL url;

        //StringBuilder object to store the message retrieved from the server
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            //Initializing Url
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            //Creating an httmlurl connection
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            //Configuring connection properties
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //Creating an output stream
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

            //Writing parameters to the request
            //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String response;
                //Reading server response
                while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(response);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL){
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(s+"\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String id){
        StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(requestURL+id);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String s;
            while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(s+"\n");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

**Config**

```js
public class Config {

    public static final String URL_ADD="http://mundorpg.000webhostapp.com/app_mural_mesa_edit/addMesa.php";
    public static final String URL_GET_ALL = "http://mundorpg.000webhostapp.com/app_mural_mesa_edit/getAllMesa.php";
    public static final String URL_GET_MESA = "http://mundorpg.000webhostapp.com/app_mural_mesa_edit/getMesa.php?id=";
    public static final String URL_UPDATE_MESA = "http://mundorpg.000webhostapp.com/app_mural_mesa_edit/updateMesa.php";
    public static final String URL_DELETE_MESA = "http://mundorpg.000webhostapp.com/app_mural_mesa_edit/deleteMesa.php?id=";

    //Keys that will be used to send the request to php scripts
    //public static final String KEY_EMP_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_MESA_IDMESA = "IDMesa";
    public static final String KEY_MESA_NOME = "Nome";
    public static final String KEY_MESA_TEMATICA = "Tematica";
    public static final String KEY_MESA_SISTEMA = "Sistema";


    //JSON Tags
    public static final String TAG_JSON_ARRAY="result";
    public static final String TAG_IDMESA = "IDMesa";
    public static final String TAG_NOME = "Nome";
    public static final String TAG_TEMATICA = "Tematica";
    public static final String TAG_SISTEMA = "Sistema";

    //employee id to pass with intent
    public static final String TBMESA_ID = "mesa_id";
}
```

**PHP**

```html
<?php 
 //Importing Database Script 
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 //Getting values
 $IDMestre = $_GET['IDMestre'];
 
 //Creating sql query
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbmesa WHERE IDMestre = '$IDMestre'";
 
 //getting result 
 $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 
 //creating a blank array 
 $result = array();
 
 //looping through all the records fetched
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
  
  //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
  array_push($result,array(
   "IDMesa"=>$row['IDMesa'],
   "Nome"=>$row['Nome'],
   //"Tematica"=>$row['Tematica']
  ));
 }
 
 //Displaying the array in json format 
 echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
 
 mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: do you know you can use MySQLi with `prepared statements`? Because right now `$IDMestre` could be anything, `$IDMestre = "1'; DROP TABLE ;--"`

Comment: IDMestre is the logged-in user ID. So this variable changes as the user changes ... So I would have to set a fixed value for the ID ???

Comment: No but you have to ***clean*** the value, currently it's a `GET` value which means that the user can use anything they want by editing the URL directly, changing it to anything such as the value I put in my comment which could drop(delete) your entire table.

Comment: But in that case, I could use POST, which is the method I've been using ...

Comment: It's not that simple. POST data can still be manipulated. Any data you did not set yourself can be (and therefore should be assumed to be) manipulated. So you need to check that `$IDMestre` is the value type it *should* be, regardless of where it came from (`POST`, `GET`, `COOKIE`,etc)

Comment: Okay, but how would I do that ???

Comment: [Use the power of the internet to find the answers you seek](https://www.dreamhost.com/blog/2013/05/22/php-security-user-validation-and-sanitization-for-the-beginner/)